# Не тормозит ли много div страницу?

Tags: вёрстка, xhtml, html, производительность

Собственно, сабж.
Много в смысле, к примеру, максимум до 50 таких тегов.

Comment: С чего бы им(div'ам) тормозить сраницу? Проверьте javascript.

Comment: Дык нет, у меня то и не тормозит ничего)
Это я просто спрашиваю.

Comment: Неуместный вопрос выходит.Оффтоп.

Comment: Почему неуместный?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

При построении каркаса страницы браузер работает именно с HTML тегами(в т.ч. блоки div) и их CSS свойствами. Ограничивать себя количеством тегов на веб-странице было бы глупо. Мощности современных ЭВМ достаточно, что бы загрузить и сформировать страницу сайта, где используется только HTML+CSS и отсутствуют вставки объемных мультимедийных файлов(большие картики, музыка, видео и тп.), практически без уловимых задержек. После загрузки и формирования веб-страницы(с вышеуказанной содержимым) она не оказывает значительной нагрузки на компьютер. Вывод: клепайте тегов столько, сколько Вам нужно. Единственное что нужно помнить в данной ситуации, это принцип расчета параметров блоков. Когда параметр блока задан явно, то браузер не тратит сил на его вычисление. Когда параметр блока задан неявно, тогда браузеру нужно исходя из разметки страницы самому узнать его значение, что отнимает некоторое время. Например: задан блок с шириной 250px, браузер принял это значение и спокойно работает дальше; задан блок с шириной 25%, браузер считает ширину родительского блока и узнает точное значение свойства width вложенного. Пример упрощен для понимания и несколько грубоват, но суть отображает. Старайтесь при большом количестве тегов задавать их свойства явно.

---

Другое дело javascript,flash,вставки мультимедиа на страницу... Они могут серьезно тормозить клиентскую часть веб-сайта. javascript и flash грузят проц даже после загрузки страницы, выполняя разнообразные вычисления. Вот с этими и подобными им элементами веб-программирования нужно быть очень осторожными. Я часто встречал сайт с огромным количеством свистелок и перделок на js, красивым флешом с 100500 эффектов и подобными чаще всего ненужными свойствами, вот такие веб-сайты реально тормозят.

---

Хочу обратить Ваше внимание, что многие верстальщики наслушавшись о ненавистной верстке таблицами вообще перестают использовать тег table. Все таблицы они создают с помощью div-ов. Это в корне неверно. Разметку страницы нельзя делать таблицей, но если на верстаемой страницы должен находиться, к примеру, прайс-лист то лучше его отобразить с использованием тега table. Это я к тому, что может именно из-за этого у Вас так много блоков на странице?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, ясно. С скриптами то я аккуратен.
Просто для реализации красивых мест использую иногда div'ов построения. Но даже с этим у меня меньше 50 на всю страницу. Не должно быть плохо.

А вот у меня кое-что и на таблицах сделано))
(нет-нет, не холивар).

Answer (score 2):

Дивы тормозить страницу могут, только если у вас куча не оптимизированных скриптов и обращений к дом, ведь чем больше тегов на странице тем больше их надо перебирать при каждом работе с деревом. Также лишние дивы влияют на обработку цсс, ведь браузер анализирует лишние элементы при поиске нужных. Но согласен даже если у вас будет 20-30 лишних дивов, на современных компьютерах это будет капля в море, но если у вас крупный проект, то лучше сначала думать, потом делать.

Answer (score 1):

Страницу «тормозить» невозможно. А вот браузер — пожалуйста. Но дело может быть в количестве обрабатываемой информации, а не в выборе. Создайте файл с миллиардом вложенных div'ов и второй — с одним единственным. Какой загрузится быстрее?
Если вы сомневаетесь по поводу целесообразности использование div-верстки против табличной, то это другой вопрос, скорее философский. А так вопрос, действительно, неуместный.

Comment: Нет, я не про типы вёрстки.

Answer (score 1):

А я вот на javascript создал страницу с `640*480` тегами див и уменя вообще комп завис я уменьшил как выяснил нужно непревышать `240*320` тегов div чтоб браузер выдержал

Comment: Хм, интересно.